# Can't start mysql after upgrade

Tags: upgrade, mysql

OK this is driving me mad. Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS (on WSL)

I am assuming that it crashed, then upgraded mysql, and now it won't start:

```
2022-08-31T16:37:29.463168Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012526] [InnoDB] Upgrade is not supported after a crash or shutdown with innodb_fast_shutdown = 2. This redo log was created with MySQL 8.0.28, and it appears logically non empty. Please follow the instructions at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading.html
2022-08-31T16:37:29.463211Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
2022-08-31T16:37:29.842520Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2022-08-31T16:37:29.842925Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2022-08-31T16:37:29.842966Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
```

I tried removing the redo logs ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 and then I get:

```
2022-09-03T16:56:05.188621Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-013862] [InnoDB] Neither found #innodb_redo subdirectory, nor ib_logfile* files in ./
2022-09-03T16:56:05.188663Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
2022-09-03T16:56:05.672331Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2022-09-03T16:56:05.672561Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2022-09-03T16:56:05.672585Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
```

Also tried removing ibdata1 and I get

```
2022-09-03T17:20:34.205872Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012592] [InnoDB] Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
2022-09-03T17:20:34.205907Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012593] [InnoDB] The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2022-09-03T17:20:34.205914Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012594] [InnoDB] If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
2022-09-03T17:20:34.205929Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012646] [InnoDB] File ./ibdata1: 'open' returned OS error 71. Cannot continue operation
2022-09-03T17:20:34.205977Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012981] [InnoDB] Cannot continue operation.
```

I guess I could downgrade to 8.0.28 but surely there is a way to recover?

I tried various innodb_force_recovery settings and none of them helped.

How do I fix this please?

Thanks

Comment: What’s left to recover? You obliterated core files that contain transaction history, system-level databases, and the metadata that tells MySQL about the databases you’ve created. At this point you may as well scrub MySQL from the system completely, reinstall, then restore from backup 

Comment: I still have the log files and ibdata1 , I just renamed them

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar issue when updating mysql to version 8.0.30
I solved it by creating the #innodb_redo folder

```
cd /var/lib/mysql

mkdir #innodb_redo

chown mysql:mysql #innodb_redo

systemctl start mysql
```

Comment: Weird if such a simple thing would fix the start up error, why doesn't mysql re-create it by it's self. Or at the least suggest it. (PS, this fixed my issue, after my mysql had a bad shutdown because disk space ran out)

Comment: But HOW did you create #innodb_redo if "#" is an illegal character.  I get a "Missing Operand" message and can't create on Fedora 39.

Comment: Put it in quotes: `mkdir "#innodb_redo"`

Answer (score 0):

> But HOW did you create #innodb_redo if "#" is an illegal character.
> I get a "Missing Operand" message and can't create on Fedora 39. –
> user3158591

```
vuser@fedora39-ssd-2TB:~$ cd /var/lib/mysql

vuser@fedora39-ssd-2TB:/var/lib/mysql$ sudo mkdir '#innodb_redo'

vuser@fedora39-ssd-2TB:/var/lib/mysql$ sudo chown mysql:mysql' #innodb_redo'

vuser@fedora39-ssd-2TB:/var/lib/mysql$ sudo service mysqld restart
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart mysqld.service
```